# Make a particular category login complusory in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I have client require to show a particular of Categories only after login only..

I have got below code which is working for Post Id, but i need it for full categories..

Below is code :

```
function my_force_login() {
   global $post;
   if (!is_single()) return;
    $ids = array(188, 185, 171); // array of post IDs that force login to read
   if (in_array((int)$post->ID, $ids) && !is_user_logged_in()) {
    auth_redirect();
  }
 }
```

How can i modified above code to work in for Category...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way from the code itself...

```
function my_force_login() {
    global $post;
    $categories=get_the_category();
    $catID = $categories[0]->term_id;
    if (!is_category()) return;

    $ids = array(5); // array of post IDs that force login to read
    if (in_array((int)$catID, $ids) && !is_user_logged_in()) {
        auth_redirect();
    }
}
```